# How to draw a border around two overlapping UIViews

Tags: uiview, border, shapes, mask

I have two UIViews that create a unique shape when overlapping and I want to draw a border around the combined views.

What is the proper method for doing this?

The UIViews are:

1. Circle image view to display a user profile image
2. A rectangle view that will container user profile data (i.e. name, dob, etc)

Here is an image of what the two view together will look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out by doing the following:

1. Setting a border on the rectangle UIView
2. Creating a `CAShapeLayer` with `UIBezierPath` to draw a semi-circle and add it to the circle `UIView's` layer in the `drawRect` method:

   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       super.draw(rect)

   ```
   let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
   let topSemiCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: userImageView.center, radius: userImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 180), clockwise: true)
   topSemiCirclePath.lineWidth = 2.0
   UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
   topSemiCirclePath.stroke()
   shapeLayer.path = topSemiCirclePath.cgPath
   userImageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
   ```

   }